# Angular Select All Pagination Issue

Tags: angular

how can i check all entries from current page in angular? If I click the Select all checkbox, all entries will be selected. But if I have a list of users containing 50 users and I paginate them 5 per page, if I press the checkbox, they will be all selected, not just the entries on the selected page. How can I resolve this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pagination-example-hq94bl?file=app/app.component.ts

My stackblitz for reference

Comment: When the `Select All` checkbox is true, do you want all of your users to be selected? OR only those 5 current users that are shown in the paginated page?

Comment: only 5 current users that are shown in the paginated page, so u can see when i click select All only 5 selected, problems come when, i move to next page, the selectAll button is checked..... and my items are not selected at that time

Comment: Let's start over. We are on Page 1. We check the `Select All`. Now all users in Page 1 are selected (hello1, hello2,.... hello5). Then we go the Page 2. The `Select All` is still checked. The users in Page 2 are not selected (hello6, hello7). Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes that is my problem, If i check Select All in Page 1 ONLY page 1 Select All and items is selected, and the page 2 Select All SHOULD NOT be selected(checked), so does the items in page 2 shouldnt be selected as well (hello6,hello7)

Comment: Got it. Please update your question to include this explanation. You should always include these details to help us understand your problem so we can help you.

Comment: ahh i see... thanks skouch for the pointers! will take note next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pagination-example-ggnmey?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I think you should use a getter function to check if all items on the page are checked then that check-all button isChecked will equal true

```
get isSelected() {
  const itemIndex = 5 * (this.page - 1);
  const itemsInCurrentPage = this.usersList.slice(itemIndex, itemIndex + 5);
  const isSelected = itemsInCurrentPage.every((item) => item.selected);
  return isSelected;
}
```

And use ngModel for input to update the state of checkbox

```
<input
        type="checkbox"
        [(ngModel)]="user.selected"
        (change)="saveSelectedList($event, user.name)"
      />
```

CheckAll button

```
<input
        type="checkbox"
        (change)="selectAll($event, page)"
        [checked]="isSelected"
      />
```

Comment: wow thanks for the tips and solution! it solve my problem!

Comment: btw if i do a getter function will i able to insert my elements into the isSelectedArray as well?